# Problems rendering output in nodejs from a neo4j server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm pretty sure this is really simple but I thought I should ask on here.
I'm creating a function in nodejs that looks for a user in a neo4j server then renders that or outputs that onto the webpage.I am able to query the neo4j sever and output that to the console fine but I do not know how to output that info to the webpage.
     /**
     * GET /
     * Neo4j Graph page.
     */

```
exports.getGraph = function(req, res) {
    res.render('graph', {
    title: 'Graph',
    user: User
  });
};



/**
* GET /
* Get user from neo4j
*/
var neo4j = require('neo4j');
var db = new neo4j.GraphDatabase('http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474');


exports.getNeoUser = function (req, res){
db.cypher({
query: 'MATCH (user:User {email: {email}}) RETURN user',
params: {
    email: 'alice@example.com',
},
}, callback);

function callback(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var result = results[0];
    if (!result) {
        console.log('No user found');
    } else {
        var user = result['user'];
        console.log(user);


    }
}

function output(req, res) {
   res.render('graph', {
    title: 'Graph',
    user: User
  });
};

};
```

If I leave it like this nothing is rendered although the app won't crash. It starts loading the page but never actually finishes. I think it might be some sort of race condition. I have tried placing this res.render inside the callback function but that results in a method undefined error.

Comment: Is the output function ever called? You can track it with a console.log

Comment: @Schahriar yea the output function is called. the output is `No user found
GET /graph - - ms - -`